# WiFi driver from Windows 7 to Ubuntu 16.4

Tags: networking, windows-7, broadcom, hp-pavilion, additional-drivers

I've got the WiFi driver for Windows 7, how do I install the .exe file for Ubuntu 16.4 ?  I've used ndiswrapper but the page seems out of date. Any suggestions?

Comment: That isn't how drivers work. Ubuntu almost never needs drivers. Is there a problem with your WiFi on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Executable files not only contain the executable code, but also information like static and dynamic data, linker info and library imports.

When you execute a .exe or linux executable, there's another program that loads the file, sets up the memory, sets up the various data and code blocks contained inside the executable file, and makes sure the executable has access to the shared library functions it needs.

On Linux, executables are stored in ELF format (Executable and Linkable Format). On Windows, executables are stored in PE format (Portable Executable).

There are also major differences between ABIs and APIs, and on Unix-y systems. Wine in an example of loader that can open, link, and execute code and libraries in PE format on an ELF-based OS.

**So, in simple words, you cannot run a windows executable(.exe) on your Ubuntu to install your drivers.**

Answer (score 0):

Simply install from the repository with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ndiswrapper
```

After that you have to set up according to [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper) tutorial continuing from the point No. 3.

Comment: The thing is, I tried ndiswrapper, but not working

Comment: The ndiswrapper does not work always, as there are several driver formats from Microsoft. It is pity that it did not work for you.